# Is it possible to prove that surfaces with compact boundary are homeomorphic by glueing disks to the boundary components?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, surfaces

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two surfaces with compact boundary and the same number of boundary components. Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be the surfaces obtained by glueing closed disks to the boundary of $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively. Is there a direct proof that if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are homeomorphic then $S_1$ and $S_2$ are also homeomorphic? I know that this can be done in the compact case using normal forms, as in Massey's book. And if the surfaces are not compact?

Comment: One can always isotope the homemorphism such that it is identity on a disk.

Comment: You need equal number of boundary components for this to hold.

Comment: Thanks, of course the same number of boundary components. I forgot to write it.

Comment: As for the isotopy idea, would you please explain more carefully how it helps to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: What you need ultimately is the "unique disc lemma": if $M$ is a surface without boundary, any two embeddings $i,j: D^2 \to M$ are nearly isotopic: there is a family of homomorphisms $F_t: M \to M$ so that $F_0$ is the identity and $i F_1 = j$ or $i F_1 = jr$, where r is reflection of the disc. In particular there is an ambient isotopy taking the image of one to the image of the other. You can then extend this to embeddings of k disjoint discs. Now you recover S from M by deleting the interiors of these discs, and the isotopies above justify that the result is unique up to homeomorphism.

Comment: The unique disc lemma is basically a form of the Schoenflies theorem (or more accurately a form of the annulus theorem in dimension 2).

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you. I am not a topologist, but I thought that a result like this should already exist. Would you please give me a reference for the unique disk lemma? Thanks again

Comment: I am sure there are many nice references but due to my own ignorance I don't know any (other than my own unpublished course notes). I can write a proof if you want; if a reference is more important I will have to punt on that.

Comment: @MikeMiller I am trying to write a paper on the dynamics of homeomorphisms of surfaces and I would like to explain why Kerekjarto / Ian Richards' characterisation of homeomorphic surfaces without boundary in terms of genus, orientability and ends is also true for surfaces with compact boundary. I don't want bother you or make you waist time. A reference that I could understand with the existence of a homeomorphism of a surface that maps a collection of n disjoint to another would be perfect. If you could  sketch a proof with little effort I could go through the details. Thanks

Comment: For a single disc, the question is answered in all dimensions [here (see the "For the rest..." paragraph)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121571/connected-sum-of-topological-manifolds/121635#121635), as an application of the Annulus Theorem. That proof should easily generalize to a finite disjoint union of discs.

Comment: @LeeMosher I read the argument for one disk, and I think I understand the idea. As for details, I am not familiar with topology in higher dimensions. When you say "nicely embedded disk" I hope that in dimension two topological obstructions do not exist and all embedded disks are nicely embedded thanks to the Jordan - Schoenflies Theorem. Is it like this?

Comment: That's correct. And you don't need any higher dimensional topology to understand the *application* of the annulus lemma.

Comment: @Lee Mosher . I wrote a detailed proof (using your ideas) that given two collections of pairwise disjoint disks, there is a homeomorphism of the surface that maps one collection to the other. Just to fill safe.  I used two facts, that I believe are correct: 1) If $C$ is a simple closed curve contained in the surface, then $C$ has a neighborhood $N$ homeomorphic to an open annulus or a Mobius band. 2) If $C$ and $D$ are two simple closed curves contained in the plane and $C$ is contained in the region bounded by $D$, then the region bounded by $C$ and $D$ is homeomorphic to an annulus.

Comment: @Lee Mosher. I don't really know how to prove this two facts, but believe that a proof could be written using triangulations.